# Different behavior in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 verses 2010 on Color Property

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a custom WPF Control that has a System.Drawing.Color property. The control works in Visual Studio 2010. for example if you select White the XAML generated is Property="White" but in 2012 or 2013 the XAML is Property="Color [White]" which is incorrect. Also want to point out that in the property Combo Box the same thing is happening 2010 displays a list of color in the format of the color Name eg. White were in 2012 or 2013 the property combo box displays a list of colors like Color[White].

Is there a setting that is different in 2012 or 2013 that can cause this or any idea why this would be happening?

Edit: Here is and Example.

The problem is simple to duplicate using a user control with one property MyColor. Creating the same control in Visual Studio 2010 and in Visual Studio 2012 produces different results. Both applications are targeting 4.0 framework and reference the same version of System.Drawing V4.0.30319. I know this example could use brushes but the actual control cannot. I am limited to using System.Drawing.Color. Any insight would great.

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Private m_MyColor As System.Drawing.Color
    Public Property MyColor As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return m_MyColor
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Drawing.Color)
            m_MyColor = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The results when setting this property in 2010:

```
<my:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" x:Name="UserControl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="98" Width="103" MyColor="White" />
```

The results wen setting this property in 2012:

```
<local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" MyColor="Color [White]"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.